# Cordova build error :transformclasseswithdexfordebug

Tags: html, cordova

[image]

When I try build app I get this error what I do?

I tried re-install node.js and cordova but it didn't work.

Comment: Please follow these recommendations: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") **must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use Ionic to build your app via Cloud.

First, run

```
ionic io init
```

Create account on Ionic website, put in the details on command live as asked.

Run the below command.

```
ionic package build android
```

No need to install anything, files will be built online.

Comment: Can i use cordova plugin with ionic ?

Comment: @M.Özdemir Yes! in-fact Ionic relies on cordova itself for API access along with that you get amazing UI with Ionic.